# segmentation fault when using pointer to pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been trying to use pointer to pointer to perform action something similar to inorder traversal in tree. here is my code

```
struct node {
    char c = '\0';
    int freq = 0;
    node *left = NULL;
    node *right = NULL;
    string code = "";
};

void appendones(node **n) {
    if ((*n) == NULL)
        ;
    else {
        (*n)->code += "1";
        appendones(&(*n)->left);
        appendones(&(*n)->right);
    }
}

void combinenodes(node *a, node *b, node **n) {
    appendones(&a);
    appendones(&b);
    //(*n)=newNode('\0',a->freq+b->freq);
    (*n)->c = '\0';
    (*n)->freq = a->freq + b->freq;
    (*n)->left = a;
    (*n)->right = b;
}

int main() {
    N = input();
    priority_queue<node, vector<node *>, compareNodefreq> nodefreq; // function object
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char s;
        int freq;

        cin >> s >> freq;
        node *n = newNode(s, freq);
        nodefreq.push(n);
    }

    // printheap(nodefreq);

    // perform combining nodes based on frequencies
    while (nodefreq.size() > 1) {
        node *a = nodefreq.top();
        nodefreq.pop();
        node *b = nodefreq.top();
        nodefreq.pop();

        node *n;
        combinenodes(a, b, &n);
        nodefreq.push(n);
    }
}
```

I get segmentation fault in  `(*n)->code+="1";` for `appendone()`.

I am not able to figure out the error. My understanding is that I am passing
the pointer by reference and performing the `appendzero()` and `appendone()`,
so I guess there is no error in that part. Also my `a` and `b` in
`combinenodes()` cannot be null because I am popping from the stack.

Could you help me figure out?

Comment: Please fix your formatting and trim the code to a [mcve].

Comment: And try to debug the code by yourself at first. These kind of errors are usually easy to be detected by a debugger.

Comment: @BaummitAugen,, fixed it , now could you help?

Comment: Could you post the full exact segfault message?  And `newNode()`?

Comment: Use a debugger and read a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about C++. No `new` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see it.  In `main()`'s `while` loop, `n` is pushed and used later, but is invalid because the node object itself is never allocated in `combinenodes()` (currently commented out).  The pointer value, then, is undefined, but in this case, turning out to be non-zero, defeating the safety check.

Comment: That's likely not the only problem. The queue declaration itself seems to implore the end of innocence among other things... http://paste.ubuntu.com/13211286/

Comment: Indeed.  Right next to that TODO you refer to, is a `node*` mention, whereas the code above uses `node`.  Still, I'm not familiar with `priority_queue` type, and execution got past pushing to reach the segfault.  The OP reply will be interesting.